# Database based on nesting JSON

Tags: mysql, database-design, json

I currently am storing raw JSON in a table as I cannot figure out how to create a table structure for the data I am using.
The JSON example I have is:

```
{
  "type": "HEADER",
  "value": "Welcome"
},
{
  "type": "LIST",
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "ITEM",
      "value": "My item!",
      "description": "Item description"
    }
  ]
},
```

The issue I have is that the objects can be nested, for example inside the object `LIST`, you can have more `LIST`, `ITEM`, or `HEADER`.
I would appreciate some suggestions on how this would translate to a relational database.

Comment: You may parse this JSON and store it into self-referencing hierarchial table - but in this case you must have definite, complete and unchangeable list of possible properties names. You may parse this JSON into hierarchial base table + additional table which stores the EAV properties set. You may... but you must prove (self-prove at first) that such parsing is needed really. If you cannot prove that you must parse, that you cannot not parse - store JSON as-is. Pre-optimization is evil...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.